# Typescript Equality issue on Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

Data is stored as:

```
 { iso: "gb", label: "United Kingdom", country: "United Kingdom" },
 { iso: "fr", label: "France", country: "France" }
```

Value passed to the Autocomplete is:

```
{ iso: "gb", label: "United Kingdom", country: "United Kingdom" }
```

Error reported in console

> Material-UI: the value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
>   None of the options match with `{"label":"United Kingdom","iso":"gb","country":"United Kingdom"}`.

Type error reported on `value={}`

> Type 'string | ICountry' is not assignable to type 'ICountry | ICountry[] | null | undefined'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ICountry | ICountry[] | null | undefined'.

Issue: Passing in data to the component doesn't set it to the corresponding option, I'm all out of ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Codesandbox of issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-firefly-zl3qd?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Box, Typography, TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import "./styles.css";
import { countries } from "./countries";
import { investors } from "./investor";
import { Formik } from "formik";

interface ICountry {
  iso: string;
  country: string;
  label: string;
}

const isoToFlag = (isoCode: string) => {
  if (isoCode) {
    return typeof String.fromCodePoint !== "undefined"
      ? isoCode
          .toUpperCase()
          .replace(/./g, char =>
            String.fromCodePoint(char.charCodeAt(0) + 127397)
          )
      : isoCode;
  }
  return "";
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const investor = investors.find(element => element.id === "123");


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          address: {
            country: investor?.legal.address.country ? investor.legal.address.country : '',
          }
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          console.log({ values, actions });
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
      >
        {({ submitForm, isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue, setValues }) => {

          return (
            <form>

              <Autocomplete
                id="country"
                options={countries}
                getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
                value={values.address.country}
                renderOption={(option: ICountry) => (
                  <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row" alignItems="center">
                    <Box mr={1}>{isoToFlag(option.iso)}</Box>
                    <Box>
                      <Typography variant="body2">{option.label}</Typography>
                    </Box>
                  </Box>
                )}
                onChange={(e: object, value: any | null) => {
                  console.log('do the types match?', typeof value === typeof values.address.country);
                  console.log('do the objects match?', value === values.address.country);
                  console.log('the objects in question', value, values.address.country);
                  console.log("                  ");
                  setFieldValue("address.country", value);
                }}
                renderInput={params => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    name="address.country"
                    label="Country"
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                )}
              />
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                size="large"
                color="primary"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                onClick={submitForm}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>
            </form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**countries.ts**

```
import { ICountry } from "./investor";

export const countries: ICountry[] = [
  {
    iso: "gb",
    label: "United Kingdom",
    country: "United Kingdom"
  },
  {
    iso: "fr",
    label: "France",
    country: "France"
  }
];
```

Comment: It's great that you have a codesandbox link but you should include all pertinent code as text in the question itself (see [ask]).  I don't know anything about material-ui, but the *type* issue seems to be that you are setting your initial value to possibly `''`, a `string`, instead of `undefined` as in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wind-orogm).  The runtime issue is likely something else.

Comment: Thanks Jcalz, I'll take your points onboard for future questions.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The full message from `Material-UI` is:

> Material-UI: the value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
> None of the options match with `{"label":"United Kingdom","iso":"gb","country":"United Kingdom"}`.
> You can use the `getOptionSelected` prop to customize the equality test.

The default equality test is simply `===`, so if your options are objects, your value would have to be one of those exact objects in order to match. A different object with the same values will not match.

But as the message tells you, you can customize the equality test via the `getOptionSelected` prop. For instance you could specify:

```
getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.iso === value.iso}
```

or you could do a deep equality check of all the object properties.

The type error can be fixed with `value={values.address.country as ICountry}`.

Here is a working version of your sandbox using v4: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-getoptionselected-b6n3s

Here is a working version with the modifications necessary for v5:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-getoptionselected-forked-rfz625?file=/src/App.tsx

The v5 version uses `isOptionEqualToValue` instead of `getOptionSelected`

```
                isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                  option.iso === value.iso
                }
```

The v5 version also changes the `renderOption` syntax as outlined in the [migration guide](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/#autocomplete).

Comment: It works to me!! to clear this warning "Material-UI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the options match with". thanks.

Comment: Same error for latest Material UI lab dependency (4.0.0-alpha.57). Seems unfixable. Whoever wants to avoid the warning, downgrade to like 4.0.0-alpha.51 (as used in Codesandbox example). That version removed a warning for me.

Comment: getOptionSelected  deprecated, use `isOptionEqualToValue` instead

Comment: same is happening when using isOptionEqualToValue

Comment: I've added a v5 sandbox using `isOptionEqualToValue`.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the **getOptionSelected (Materail-UI - 4+ support)**  property of Autocomplte component to **isOptionEqualToValue (Materail-UI - 5+ support)**

**Error:**

```
<Autocomplete
    fullWidth={true}
    label={props.label}
    margin={'noraml'}
    multiple={false}
    name={props.name}
    getOptionSelected={useCallback((option, value) => option.value === value.value)} // Materail-UI - 4+ support
    value={props.value}
    options={dropDown[props.id] || props.options}
    ref={selectRef}
    onChange={useCallback((e, v) => {
        if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
            _onChange(e, v)
        } else {
            _onChange(e, {label: ''})
        }
    })}
/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<Autocomplete
    fullWidth={true}
    label={props.label}
    margin={'noraml'}
    multiple={false}
    name={props.name}
    isOptionEqualToValue={useCallback((option, value) => option.value === value.value, [])} // Materail-UI - 5+ support
    value={props.value}
    options={props.options}
    ref={selectRef}
    id='disable-clearable'
    disableClearable
    renderInput={useCallback(params => (
        <TextField {...params} label='disableClearable' variant='standard' />
    ), [])}
    onChange={useCallback((e, v) => {
        if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
            _onChange(e, v)
        } else {
            _onChange(e, {label: ''})
        }
    }, [])}
/>
```