# What is `getOptionSelected` and `getOptionLabel` in Material UI with an example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was going through Mui Documentation, in the `Autocomplete` component section I got two `props`,`getOptionLabel` and `getOptionSelected` which I got the definition but I did not understand it properly. So it will great if anyone can give me the proper definition in a simple way with example

Comment: You can find some information in this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504777/typescript-equality-issue-on-material-ui-autocomplete/61506008#61506008

Comment: note that `getOptionSelected` has been renamed to `isOptionEqualToValue` on mui version 5

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`getOptionLabel` is use to show the text in the dropdown

EX: autocomplete array

```
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 }
}

<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.year.toString()} // in the dropdown the option text will be year,if we use like option.title then it will show the title of the movie in dropdown
......
```

`getOptionSelected` this is use to determine the selected value of given array

```
<Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionSelected={(option) => option.year === 1994}
....
//this will select all the option which has year as 1994 and make the background of that option darker
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e47oi)

Comment: but options also do that? What's the difference?

Comment: `options` is the list that required to populate the drop down, and `getOptionLabel` is the thing that decide which text should be shown in the dropdown options
in above ex: year will be shown as the  text of the option and if i change `getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}` then it will show the title as the option text i nthe dropdown

Comment: Thanks!.
I have been trying to modify the autocomplete and this is what I missed to highlight the selected

Comment: Also, if Autocomplete is a controlled element, in that case, you will have to set the "value" with a value of type "{ title: string, year: number }", when say you select a value from the dropdown, otherwise this won't work!

Answer (score 31):

#### `getOptionLabel`

Like Kalhan said, getOptionLabel sets the string label in the dropdown.
For example:

```
    const users = [
        { userName: 'bob',  age: 20, message:[...] },
        { userName: 'jane', age: 43, message:[...] },
        { userName: 'joe',  age: 88, message:[...] },
    }

    <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={users}
        getOptionLabel={(user) => user.userName }
```

#### getOptionSelected

To clarify, getOptionSelected is used to determine if the selected value (i.e. the string in the autocomplete text field when you select an item from the dropdown) matches an option (in this case, user object) from the options array.

According to the [Material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/), `getOptionSelected` has the following signature, where option is the option to test and value is the value to test against:

```
function(option: T, value: T) => boolean
```

As an example, by using getOptionSelected, I can get the full user object when an element is selected from the dropdown (also avoids warnings such as, "The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid...")

```
    const users = [
        { userName: 'bob',  age: 20, message:[...] },
        { userName: 'jane', age: 43, message:[...] },
        { userName: 'joe',  age: 88, message:[...] },
    }

    <Autocomplete
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={users}
        getOptionLabel={(user) => user.userName }
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.userName === value.userName }
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            this.setValue(newValue);
        }}
 
        // more code

    setValue = (newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue); //  { userName: 'jane', age: 43, message:[...] }
    }
```

Comment: Please Jenna, can you tell me how to use getOptionSelected with options created dynamically? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886987/material-ui-autocomplete-with-options-dynamically-created-warning-use-the-getop

Comment: @Jenna Could you tell me when did getOptionSelected will call, For me, It's calling when the dropdown list is opened and closed. This is happening in dev env. But in prod, it is calling only on the dropdown list opens

Comment: how does this with with the multiple flag (more the one item allowed to be selected in auto complete).

Comment: `getOptionSelected` has been [renamed](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#%E2%9C%85-rename-getoptionselected) to `isOptionEqualToValue`.